# python how to intentionally leave indented line blank?

Tags: python

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    uid, profile = line.split('\t')
    try:
        process(profile)
    except:
        # do nothing and skip this profile
```

I would like to skip all profiles that throw exceptions. But python gives me

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

at the line "# do nothing and skip this profile".

How do I tell python to do nothing?

Answer (score 4):

The Python "NOP" is [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements)

```
...
except:
    pass
```

That said, never use bare `except` clauses. They catch things like a `KeyboardInterrupt` that you (almost) absolutely NEVER want to handle yourself. If there's nothing SPECIFIC you're catching, do `except Exception`

Answer (score 3):

Use the `pass` keyword:

```
except:
    pass
```

`pass` is basically a do-nothing placeholder.

---

Also, it is generally considered a bad practice to have a bare `except` like that.  As explained [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except), it will catch *all* exceptions, even those that are unrelated.

Instead, you should catch a specific exception:

```
except Exception:
```